# SSIS ETL Pattern based on Rowversion occasionally missing rows, how to correct?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have been using an SSIS pattern based around rowversion to synchronize records between two databases by looking at only rows in the source that have been inserted or updated since the last package run. Note data is never deleted from the source table, which is a prerequisite for this SSIS pattern.

**However lately we discovered despite running daily our import has actually missed rows from last month, leaving them out of our data warehouse entirely!
This is what i'm seeking a solution to..how can we change our ETL pattern to avoid this problem, without going back to reading every row from source every day?**

From internet searching we found an explanation for why this might be happening, but not a solution. The flaw seems to be related to the fact that the SQL column rowversion gets its value when an insert/update starts, not when it commits, which can lead to rows not being available at package execution time, but getting committed later with rowversion values less than your stored ETLRowversion value, so next time your job runs they get skipped.

In brief our pattern currently is like this: (I've left out steps involving index maintenance, etc for simplicity.)

> - Get the last active rowversion from source DB using `min_active_rowversion()` call that `@MaxRv`.
> - Get the rowversion value as of last successful execution of our SSIS task (stored in our data warehouse in a table called `ETLRowversions`). Call that `@LSERV`.
> - Read rows from the source table `WHERE rowversion is >= @LSERV and rowversion is <= @MaxRv`
> - For each row read, check if the row exists in target DB (if so add the row to an update staging table) or not (in which case, insert it directly into Target table)
> - Update the Target table using the update staging table
> - Update `ETLrowVersions` table in our data warehouse with the `@MaxRv` value.

**Edit:** Comments have suggested to implement Change Tracking and Snapshot Isolation as the best solution to this problem. Unfortunately both change tracking and allow_snapshot_isolation are both OFF for the source database..and I am pessimistic about my chances of getting these features turned on. For better or worse our BI concerns carry far less weight than performance concerns of the production application/DB that is our source.

Comment: **Don't** use `rowversion`. It's only meant for optimistic concurrency. It's not guaranteed to have sequential values. SQL Server offers [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) since 2005 at least which is a *lot* faster and can track deleted rows too.

Comment: Where we follow a pattern like this we offset backwards on the start of the refresh window (i.e. subtract X from your variable @LSERV where X is small but enough to provide an overlap between one extract and the next).

Comment: With change tracking enabled, the server automatically stores the PK values for new, modified *and* deleted rows. It can return all PK values modified since a specific database version which means you can easily ask for only the PKs that changed since the last load. You can joint those results with the source table to only load modified rows. This is far faster than the full table scan required when working with the unindexable rowversion

Comment: BTW `rowversion` is unindexable **precisely** because it's not meant to be used for querying

Comment: @BarneyL rowversion isn't meant for querying. No matter how small or large the window, the data can and *will* be wrong. Never mind the full table scan required to select just a few values

Comment: PS: Change tracking is available in all editions and versions since 2005 (even Express)

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos Change tracking may have been available since 2005 but not everyone has the luxury of being able to design their own source system. If our external system vendor gives us row versions then we have no choice but to make do with them.

Comment: @BarneyL you can't. Because `rowversion` doesn't want the way you think it does. And yes, you can use change tracking with *any* database simply because it's a transparent feature. All you need to do is enable it on a table and add a `JOIN CHANGE_TABLE(...)` clause in your query. On the other hand, with rowversion you *can't* get reliable changes, period.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos So to clarify your proposal is that we invalidate the support contract with our system provider by making unauthorised changes to their database product?

Comment: @BarneyL as for why you can't, it's because the server *knows* it's not meant for querying. It's only supposed to change when the row changes. It doesn't even have to *in*crement. When the server has to update a lot of rows it won't generate new values one by one, it will generate and use entire batches at once. If the transaction rolls back, there will be gaps. If multple connections do a lot of work, there will be gaps. If you try to read data while such operations are in progress, you'll get invalid rowversion numbers and end up with a "last" value that's bigger than new rows

Comment: @BarneyL you already use features in unsupported ways, in fact, ways that are **guaranteed** to fail. Besides, is some third-party vendor going to say that using a *SQL Server feature* is unauthorized? By *whom*? Would they take that up with Microsoft's perhaps?  Or should you contact the local subsidiary for them?

Comment: @BarneyL seriously now. Even with change tracking, you may miss rows unless you use snapshot isolation. That's because in the time between the start and end of a query *other* connections will be changing the data. By starting a transaction in snapshot isolation mode you get a consistent view, even though the underlying data changes. *Maybe* using snapshot isolation will result in consistent rowversion numbers as well. Start a tx with snaphsot,*then* take the max change tracking or version number, and only then start reading rows from your last stored version

Comment: @BarneyL if the vendor starts getting imaginative you can ask them to say *in writing* to explain with SQL Server reliability and data management features they don't support. What then, no backups? No clusters? It's surprising how fast they back off

Comment: Rowversion is indexable - though the docs warn against this on the grounds that any update to the row will cause it to move in the index so there will be a penalty on writes that may not be justified by the read requirement. The points about sequential seem irrelevant as they aren't assuming that or relying on that.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos I'll leave it there for now. You must be very lucky always working with source system providers who a) know what they should be doing and\or will implement it for you b) don't invalidate your support contract if you make any changes to their database implementation. Sadly not all of us have that luxury and so have to make do with what we have. I'd love to do more but that's not an option for us, we make do with what we have. All the best, Barney.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm relating my own experience trying to pull changes. That's how I found out that you can't trust that rowversion increments reliably. *Then* I found the articles that explain why that happens.

Comment: @BarneyL try snapshot isolation. You need a consistent view of the source tables while reading from them.